# Compilation error while building chromium

Tags: visual-studio-2010, webkit, cygwin, chromium

I am trying to build chromium on Windows 7 64 bit using VS2010.
I am getting error in building webkit.Here is error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: generate_supplemental_dependency, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 11/11/2012 12:22:17 AM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "../../../../..\build\Debug\obj\generate_supplemental_dependency\generate_supplemental_dependency.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>CustomBuild:
1>  Resolving [Supplemental=XXX] dependencies in all IDL files
1>        6 [main] perl 5908 child_copy: linked dll data write copy failed, 0xD2A000..0xD49C48, done 0, windows pid 5972, Win32 error 487
1>  Can't call method "fileName" without a package or object reference at ../bindings/scripts/IDLParser.pm line 113.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 255.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:09.56
2>------ Build started: Project: webcore_bindings_sources, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>Build started 11/11/2012 12:22:27 AM.
2>InitializeBuildStatus:
2>  Touching "../../../../..\build\Debug\obj\webcore_bindings_sources\webcore_bindings_sources.unsuccessfulbuild".
2>CustomBuild:
2>  HTMLEntityTable
2>  Running call "C:\chrome\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\..\..\..\..\..\third_party\cygwin\setup_env.bat" 
2>  make: *** No rule to make target `/cygdrive/c/chrome/src/build/Debug/\obj\global_intermediate\supplemental_dependency.tmp', needed by `/cygdrive/c/chrome/src/build/Debug/\obj\global_intermediate\webcore\bindings\V8SpeechRecognitionEvent.cpp'.  Stop.
2>  make: *** No rule to make target `/cygdrive/c/chrome/src/build/Debug/\obj\global_intermediate\supplemental_dependency.tmp', needed by `/cygdrive/c/chrome/src/build/Debug/\obj\global_intermediate\webcore\bindings\V8SpeechRecognitionEvent.cpp'.  Stop.
2>  HTMLNames, and also WebKitFontFamilyNames, and also SVGNames, and also MathMLNames, and also XLinkNames, and also XMLNSNames, and also XMLNames
2>  Failed to read names from file: C:/chrome/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/html/HTMLTagNames.in at C:\chrome\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\dom\make_names.pl line 290.
2>  Traceback (most recent call last):
2>    File "scripts/action_makenames.py", line 185, in <module>
2>    File "scripts/action_makenames.py", line 167, in main
2>  AssertionError
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
2>
2>Build FAILED.
```

I search this error a lot on net and most of the solutions were related to cygwin rebasing.
they have mentionded to use following commad to rebase cygwin

> ash.exe rebaseall

But I am not able to find ash or rebase all in cygwin director in third_party/cygwin folder.

Any idea about this error?

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that your cygwin installation does not contain `(d)ash` package. The best way to install `cygwin` with all the dependencies need for chrome is to run the `cygwin-downloader.py`.

This will install all the required dependencies, including `ash`.

Or else if you prefer to install ash.exe only, run the setup search for package `dash` include this package and proceed with the setup.

Comment: I am not able to find cygwin-downloader.py in webkit/tools folder.Any idea where to locate it in chromium source?

Comment: also I dont have cygwin setup and cygwin directory was downloaded with chromium source